# Bootstrap select dropdown arrow not showing in smaller screen resolution

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using `bootstrap` dropdown in my site. Right now I am checking site in firefox and it will display fine in original browser size.

Its create issue when i am checking in different sizes with using `cnt + shift + M.`

```
<select class="form-control" id="test">
 <option value="1">demo1</option>
 <option value="2">demo2</option>
</select>
```

**Original**

[image]

**Small size without Down Arrow**

[image]

Please help me to solve this problem. Thank You.

Comment: Please post the code which surrounds the `<select>` tag.

Comment: It shows the down arrow by me when I shrink the page. Please provide your HTML and CSS.

Comment: I have the exact same problem, although it took me a while to figure out it was caused when the screen resolution is changed.  What browser are you using?  Sorry I can't help at this stage: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39056651/select-control-is-missing-its-arrow-icon-on-a-form-using-bootstrap-with-firefox

Comment: I am using latest version of firefox. ok upvote the question so we can get answer fast. @tyebillion