# Select control is missing its arrow icon on a form using Bootstrap (with Firefox browser)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a select control on a form using Bootstrap (with Firefox browser), but it is missing its arrow icon on the right:

[image: select example]

Here is the relevant HTML I used:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <form id="form" method="post" action="process.php">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="lbl" for="choose">Choose</label>
            <select class="form-control" id="choose" name="choose" required>
                <option value="Foo">Foo</option>
                <option value="Bar">Bar</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <input type="submit" name="button" value="Submit" class="btn-primary">
        <input type="button" name="cancel" value="Cancel" class="btn-primary" onclick="clkcnc();">
    </form>
</div>
```

This is the only CSS I used on these elements:

```
body {
    font-size: 20px;
}
.form-control {
    padding-top: 6px;
}
.lbl {
    padding-top: 6px;
}
```

I wanted to use the form-control class to make the control look like other controls when using Bootstrap on my forms, but this select control looks more like a text input.

**Update**

This problem is related to using a different resolution (via responsive design mode in Firefox).  In my case the resolution is 480 x 854.  When I turn off the mode, so the browser is displaying within a screen resolution of 1600 x 900, the select control appears as normal with the arrow icon on the right.  Unfortunately I need the page to work in a narrow resolution.  Here are the meta settings in my base page set up:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, 
user-scalable=no">
```

Here is the result of the fiddle from link2pk below:

[image: Result of fiddle from below]

Comment: shows as expected for me in Firefox - maybe other CSS is conflicting with the class / id?

Comment: maybe you are overriding the css or something try https://jsfiddle.net/link2pk/25pdt6sx/2/ on your firefox

Comment: I also cannot reproduce. The arrow disappears when `padding-top` is more than 25px tho. Just don't use `padding`

Comment: @link2pk I discovered that it does not work in responsive design mode in Firefox (try a resolution of 480 x 854).

Comment: @gavgrif See above comment!

Comment: on my firefox 47.0, dropdown is there. see http://imgur.com/a/W6jVV . Which firefox version are you using?

Comment: @link2pk A strange discrepancy, I'm using version 48.0.

Comment: @tyebillion it's there in 48.0.2 here: http://imgur.com/a/SSQon according to this https://jsfiddle.net/link2pk/25pdt6sx/2/ 
If possible can you show the live url where you are having this issue?
Are you on windows or mac? maybe its there in windows

Comment: @link2pk I just ran your fiddle and the arrow disappears when I reduce the resolution to 480 x 854 in Firefox.  I'm running Linux Mint 17.3 Cinnamon edition.

Comment: @link2pk I added a picture of your fiddle to my question.

Comment: @tyebillion check this gif http://imgur.com/tYKiJHw . when i did ⌘+shift+m to change to responsive mode, dropdown arrow was not there. Then I refreshed the page and dropdown arrow came back. very strange.

Comment: Meanwhile you can use custom select like http://jsfiddle.net/fm5Jt/122/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122793/discussion-between-link2pk-and-tyebillion).

Answer (score 5):

1. Upgrade to Bootstrap v5.2 +
2. try form-select instead of form-control if using Bootstrap v5 (see: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/forms/select/ )

Comment: Thanks, using Bootstrap v5.2, that did it :)